# Exclude META-INF directory from war

Tags: maven, maven-war-plugin

I know my question may seem odd, but how can I exclude whole meta-inf directory from war? I tried:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3</version>
<configuration>
    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <webResources>
        <resource>
            <directory>WebContent</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </webResources>
</configuration>
```

I also tried:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <packagingExcludes>META-INF/*</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The reason why I need this is because I'm trying to generate an archive which will be a kind of a patch for a deployed application - so I don't want to overwrite unnecessary files.

Comment: I think that this is the job of the archiver component (http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html) to generate META-INF contents. Not sure if you can configure it not to include that directory when packaging your WAR. You might just use an assembly to generate the special WAR you want.

Comment: Simply removed it from your project. Apart from that during the archiving process an META-INF will be generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following `configuration` in your `war` plugin:

```
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

source -
https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-archive-configuration.html